# Passing values to child class which inherits from PageNumberPagination from drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have to use PageNumberPagination (from drf) in many of my views, I used to define a **custom class** inheriting PageNumberPagination in each of my views.py, like -

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class CustonmPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 3
    page_query_param = "pageNumber"


class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    pagination_class = CustonmPageNumberPagination
```

Now I'm trying to define a helper class in project level file and call this class whenever required.

so my custompagination.py file is -

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class CustomPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 3
    page_query_param = "pageNumber"
```

and then I can use it like -

```
   from backend.pagination import CustomPageNumberPagination

    class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = MySerializer
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        pagination_class = CustonmPageNumberPagination
```

But I also want to pass the value of page_size to my CustomPageNumberPagination whenever the class is called from my views, so as to get exact page size for each of my views.

I understand class takes arguments in the **init** method so when I try something like

```
class CustomPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.count = count
    page_size = 3
    page_query_param = "pageNumber"
```

and when trying to call this class

```
pagination_class = CustomPageNumberPagination("gh")
```

it gives an error 'CustomPageNumberPagination' object is not callable.

Any help on how can I pass values?

Answer (score 1):

The pagination class is instantiated inside paginator property defined inside GenericAPIView

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    @property
    def paginator(self):
        return CustomPageNumberPagination(4)
```

Comment: Will try and let you know, I was trying to read the drf code for this but then...

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this seems quite complicated to me. If I do what you recommended I'm unable to get pagination buttons to change page number. I can manually type the url and it works but let's leave it for now.